# Howto publish in Ubuntu App Sotre an app that was not writted with Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I have written a game for Ubuntu Phone, without using Ubuntu SDK. I have written, compiled and tested it on Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition. I have the binary file and .desktop launcher for it, plus couple of wav files with sound effects. 
How do I go about oackaging the app and publishing to Ubuntu App Store?
I wrote the game in Lazarus (Freepascal) on the phone itself, below few screenshots, so you can see that Ubuntu SDK is not really the only mean to make apps working on Ubuntu Touch devices:
[app icon, launching and spread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNw2Z.jpg)
[gameplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBS7e.jpg)

Comment: At this point I can send my app to anybody as a download link, and people can install and use it on Ubuntu Devices like my phone, yet, I cannot publish it via the Ubuntu App Store. Ubuntu Touch is such an amazing, open, powerful operating system, yet Ubuntu App Store seems so restrictive, as nowhere can I find way to publish anything that wasn't made in Ubuntu SDK.
I have even started a blog to discuss broad possibilities with Ubuntu Touch platform as soon as we go out of the box, and beyond the proposed SDK:
http://kriscode.blogspot.tw/2016/09/freepascal-development-for-ubuntu-phone.html

Comment: Perhaps I found a solution, but need to understand and try, following this post: http://notyetthere.org/on-manually-creating-click-packages/

Comment: Click approach doesn't work. I am able to build click package, and also to install the package locally. The problem however is, that after installing the click package, the automatically created app launcher runs the app via an AppArmor confinement, by prefixing the app in the launcher with aa-exec-click.
Apparently Xmir apps do not run confined. Unless there is a way to create a proper profile, which I don't know.
This is however a separate roblem and I will create a separate question for it. I will accept the click method as a valid response to how the question is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fond the answer on G+: just package the app as click, which can be done directly on the phone itself: # click build 
an the directory has to contain the binary, the data like sounds, images, config files etc, AND 2 files for the click package builder that you can make yourself in text editor: manifest.json and .json, like explained here: http://click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file-format.html